# Jelly Bean 4.2 webview display problems

Tags: android, webview, android-4.2-jelly-bean

My app doesn't display it's webview on our Jelly Bean(a htc evo 4g lte), but runs fine on most everything with an api 16 and lower. I've looked around the net for the last few hours and have yet to find a satisfactory answer as to why my webview won't appear on 4.2 phones.

Here is the MainActivity,

```
package com.example;

import java.net.URL;
import android.R.color;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import com.example.*;
import com.google.ads.*;




public class MainActivity extends Activity {


private WebView webView;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Request an ad
    AdView ad = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    ad.loadAd(new AdRequest());

    Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    myButton.setBackgroundColor(0);
    myButton.setBackgroundResource(color.darker_gray);
    myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
        public void onClick(View v) {  
            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

            sharingIntent.setType("text/html");

            sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml("<p>This is the text that will be shared.</p>"));

            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,"Share using"));  
                }  
    }); 

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(webView, DISPLAY_SERVICE);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("http://example.com");
    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
    WebView webView=(WebView)this.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT); 
    myWebView.onPause();
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
    webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    WebView myWebView1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    myWebView1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.canGoBack();
    WebSettings config = webView.getSettings();
    config.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


}


    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (webView != null && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return true;


}


}
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? Can you share the stack trace?

Comment: No I'm not getting any errors, the url loads fine. I can highlight the text on the page. The problem is that all of the content(like the text) on the page is completely white.

Comment: Did you solve this problem?please share answer.